# promethus can not get metrics everytime resultting gaps when displaying metrics

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I deploy  several  flink on k8s in standalone mode , and export their metrics  by one promethus-pushgateway.

The Problem is that:
**the metrics Data arrives at promethus intermittently ,resultting to gaps between dots when displayed in grafana**

[click me, show the gapped graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt3fe.png)

---

promethus target:

```
monitoring/pushgateway/0 (1/1 up)
Endpoint: http://172.19.88.111:9091/metrics
State   : UP
Labels: endpoint="tcp" instance="172.19.88.111:9091" job="pushgateway" namespace="flink-sql" pod="pushgateway-76d64545dd-6prdn" service="pushgateway"
```

I query the pushgateway directly ,but can not get all metris every time

```sh
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:17 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0

bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:18 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0

bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:18 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:19 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:20 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:20 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="jobmanager",instance="",job="model"} 20
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:20 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:21 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:22 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:22 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:23 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0

bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:23 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="jobmanager",instance="",job="model"} 20

bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:24 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0

bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:24 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="172_19_90_175",instance="",job="model1122"} 8
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:25 UTC 2021

bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:26 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0

bash-5.0# date  &&  curl  -s http://pushgateway.flink-sql:9091/metrics      | grep flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers
Mon May 24 07:15:27 UTC 2021
# HELP flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers numRegisteredTaskManagers (scope: jobmanager)
# TYPE flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers gauge
flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers{host="flink_jobmanager",instance="",job="flink-sql"} 0
```

The config in my flink-conf.yaml

```yaml
metrics.reporter.promgateway.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayReporter
metrics.reporter.promgateway.host: pushgateway.flink-sql
metrics.reporter.promgateway.port: 9091
metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName: flink-sql
metrics.reporter.promgateway.randomJobNameSuffix: false
metrics.reporter.promgateway.deleteOnShutdown: false
metrics.reporter.promgateway.interval: 3 SECONDS
```

even set `promethus Scrape  interval`  `metrics.reporter.promgateway.interval` to 1 second , no effect ;

Comment: I already experienced something similar and it was due to high memory usage. Basically, check if your Flink jobs are in backpressure and check the memory usage with `htop`

Comment: @Felipe  no luck even  withnot flink job running ,

Comment: I would not try to scrape Flink every 1 second, 5 seconds or 15 seconds is enough. I think this could be the source of the gaps since one scrape did not finished and Prometheus already started another scrap.
Are the gaps appearing only for the `flink_jobmanager_numRegisteredTaskManagers` or for others as well?

Comment: maybe you can try to register 2 TM and test. Then you register 4 TM and test. Then 6 TM and test. If you don't have problem with 2 TM, at some point it will appear when you register more TMs.

Comment: yeah ,this happens to  all the metrics

Answer (score 0):

I guess that:

- The gapped graph  results  from promethus does not have successive  data stored.
- Prometheus' metrics data are from PushaGateWay.
- PushGateWay's metrics data  are from JobManager/TaskManager.
- The data reported from JobManager/TaskManager to PushaGateWay is not cached by PushaGateWay.
- So when  promethus query Pushgateway periodly,it only get what pushgateway has on the moment , not all the data  JobManager/TaskManager reported .

What I experienced seems this way,But it's not  conclusive .PushGateWay  must  play a role  after all .
Of course ,It's  not considered  Whether Flink's  metric reportor has reported data  periodly  as expected or not

Now I get gap problem  solveed by new solution that promethus scrape data  from Jobmanage/Taskmanager directly .

Answer (score 0):

Your push interval should be ~equal to or more than the Prometheus scrape interval. Also setting Prometheus scrape interval to 1sec might cause issues in Prometheus, just set the scrape interval to a higher value (~15s) and same for the push interval.